# Что означает такая запись на с++

Tags: c++

```
res += fun_res << (count++ * 3)
```

Что означает эта запись `+=` понимаю, а дальше не очень

Comment: Примерно то же самое, что `res = res + ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res += fun_res << (count++ * 3)
```

Начинаем с конца.

```
(count++ * 3)
```

Дает значение `count*3`, после чего значение переменной `count` будет увеличено на 1.

```
fun_res << (count++ * 3)
```

Значение `fun_res` побитово сдвигается влево на число бит, равное тому результату умножения на 3, о котором сказано выше.

```
res += fun_res << (count++ * 3)
```

К значению `res` прибавляется результат побитового сдвига, после чего получившаяся сумма опять записывается в `res`.

Но! все это может быть совсем не так, если это не простые целые числа, а какие-то объекты пользовательских типов... Так что всегда приводите **всю** информацию - вы же не партизан на допросе...

Answer (score -1):

Переменная res = переменная res + переменная count + 1 * 3